# Running Flask raises "WinError 10038"

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Running a simple Flask app raises `OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`. The page is not served in the browser. What does the error mean? How do I fix it?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger pin code: 294-294-951
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 474, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "C:\Users\kdalal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 460, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2194) was [fixed](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/commit/09b330b5b00ef0bcc396ea42f8b894c85c003926) in Werkzeug 0.12.1. Upgrade to the latest version:

```
pip install -U werkzeug
```

Answer (score 4):

Today, September 2022, I am using Werkzeug 2.2.2 and I was getting exactly the same issue:

> OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

I tried using the environment variables `FLASK_DEBUG` and/or `FLASK_ENVIRONMENT`, since this error only appeared when I run the Flask app in debug mode, but I kept getting this socket error. Really frustrating not being able to use Flask in debug mode.

After more researching, I found the solution. I opened the command prompt (cmd) as an Administrator, and ran the following command `netsh winsock reset` then restarted the computer. The error doesn't appear anymore when I run Flask in debug mode now.

It would seem this is an issue only affecting those still with Vista or Windows 7, when the Winsock2 gets corrupted. More details can be found in these links:

[how-and-why-to-perform-a-netsh-winsock-reset-on-windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/785351/how-and-why-to-perform-a-netsh-winsock-reset-on-windows/)

[Microsoft support - Reset Winsock for Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-determine-and-to-recover-from-winsock2-corruption-in-windows-server-2003-in-windows-xp-and-in-windows-vista-a6663bfa-40d1-ead7-d790-7869ee9448e7)

[Original solution found on Karatos](https://blog.karatos.in/a?ID=00500-54ac64d7-8163-4162-a7cb-d0285c9cec3a)

Hopefully, this can be useful to someone with the same problem.