# Flask app throwing an error when I shut down the app

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, pyenv

My code:

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient(<connectionlink>)
app.db = client.blog


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        entry_content = request.form.get("content")
        formatted_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        app.db.entries.insert_one({"content":entry_content, "date":formatted_date})
        
    entries_with_date = [
        (
            entry["content"],
            entry["date"],
            datetime.datetime.strptime(entry["date"], "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%b %d")
        )
        for entry in app.db.entries.find({})
    ]
    return render_template("index.html", entries=entries_with_date)
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (serve_forever):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.1\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.1\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 766, in serve_forever
super().serve_forever(poll_interval=poll_interval)
File "C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.1\Lib\socketserver.py", line 233, in serve_forever
ready = selector.select(poll_interval)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.1\Lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.1\Lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

The database and the app both seem to be just working fine but when I set flask debug to 1 and run the app I get this error. Seems to be a py-env issue from what I read on the traceback, but I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: Maybe it is the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355301/running-flask-raises-winerror-10038

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue and I've traced it back to werkzeug 2.2.3 when running in vs code. With 2.2.2 it doesn't raise an exception.
I've raised the issue here: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2627