# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket FLASK

Tags: python, flask

At some point i was messing around with flask sockets but ended up not using the libraries, I then reverted my code but ended up getting socket errors even though my code no longer contained anything remotely related to bi-directional socket connections.

The following is my code (sorry for the spaggetti i'm still terrible at coding):

```
import time, json, xxhash, threading, random
from flask import Flask, request
from string import digits
from random import choice
app = Flask(__name__)

target = 5
last_block, key = time.time(), int(''.join(choice(digits) for i in range(8)))
pending_transactions, pending_data = [], []

user_data = {}

def import_user_data(username):
    with open(f'user_data\\{username}.json', 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def export_user_data(username, data):
    with open(f'user_data\\{username}.json', 'w') as f:
        return json.dump(data, f)

def create_user_data(user, password):
    try:
        with open(f'user_data\\{user}.json', 'x') as f:
            json.dump({"password": password, "balance": 0, "transactions": []}, f)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

def get_balance(user):
    data = import_user_data(user)
    return data.get("balance")

def post_transaction(amount, sender, recipient, memo):
    txid = xxhash.xxh64(random.randbytes(64)).hexdigest()

    if sender != "Mainnet":
        user = import_user_data(sender)
        if len(user["transactions"]) >= 25:
            user["transactions"].pop(-1)
        user["transactions"].append({"txid": txid, "sender": sender, "recipient": recipient, "amount": amount, "memo": memo})
        export_user_data(sender, user)

    user = import_user_data(recipient)
    if len(user["transactions"]) >= 25:
        user["transactions"].pop(-1)
    user["transactions"].append({"txid": txid, "sender": sender, "recipient": recipient, "amount": amount, "memo": memo})
    export_user_data(recipient, user)

    return txid
def payout(username):
    global target
    data = import_user_data(username)

    reward = target * 10 + 1

    data["balance"] += reward
    export_user_data(username, data)
    post_transaction(reward, "Mainnet", username, f"mining reward! (target: {target})")

def transfer(sender, recipient, amount):
    data = import_user_data(sender)

    if not float(data.get("balance")) < float(amount):
        data["balance"] -= float(amount)
        export_user_data(data, sender)

        data = import_user_data(recipient)
        data["balance"] += float(amount)

        export_user_data(data, recipient)

    return {"txid": post_transaction(amount, sender, recipient, memo)}

def new_block(block, last_block):
    global target, key

    t = block - last_block
    key = int(''.join(choice(digits) for i in range(8)))

    if t > 80:
        target -= 1
    if t < 50:
        target += 1

    for i in range(0, len(pending_transactions)):
        pass

def chain():
    global target, last_block

    try:
        while True:

            if time.time() - last_block > 81:
                target -= 1
                last_block = time.time()
                time.sleep(30)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@app.route("/create_account")
def create_acc():
    try:
        e, t = time.time(), target

        if request.json["hash"] == xxhash.xxh64(request.json["nonce"], seed=int(e)).hexdigest():

            username, password = xxhash.xxh64(random.randbytes(64)).hexdigest(), xxhash.xxh64(random.randbytes(64)).hexdigest()
            create_user_data(username, password)

            return {"output": True, "username": username, "password": password}

    except Exception as e:
        return {"output": False, "info": e}

@app.route("/mine", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mine():
    global key, last_block, target

    if request.method == "GET":
        return {"target": target, "key": key}
    else:
        e, t = time.time(), target

        if request.json["hash"] == xxhash.xxh64(request.json["nonce"], seed=key).hexdigest():
            new_block(e, last_block)

            last_block = e

            payout(request.json["username"])

            return {"output": True, "info": "you have submitted a valid block!"}
        else:
            return {"output": False, "info": "your submission is invalid"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = threading.Thread(target=chain)
    c.start()

    app.run(debug=True, port=80, host="127.0.0.1")
```

Let me know if more information should be provided

1. I reinstalled Flask along with its dependancies.
2. I followed the steps in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355301/running-flask-raises-winerror-10038](https://stackoverflow.com) forum post
3. I restarted my computer yet the error persisted, although the error only pops up once every few minutes.

EDIT: The following is the error along with the traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jerrb\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 804, in serve_forever
    super().serve_forever(poll_interval=poll_interval)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socketserver.py", line 232, in serve_forever
    ready = selector.select(poll_interval)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\selectors.py", line 324, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\selectors.py", line 315, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback. It should tell you what line led to the error, and anything leading up to that point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WinError+10038+%5Bflask%5D -- just search for the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of fuss and scrolling through the internet, ChatGPT managed to solve my problem within 3 minutes. I solved my issue by **reinstalling Winsock2 completely** using the following cmd commands.

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

The problem was caused by heavy corruption of Winsock2